# Mapping a stream to the position in an array

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

Let's say I have an array with some objects.

```
Obj[] objects = new Obj[]{Obj1, Obj2, Obj3, Obj4};
```

Out of curiosity, is it possible to map a stream to the position that they are in their origin array?
For example, map it to `1,2,3,4` in this case?

I assume that something like this would not work.

```
Arrays.stream(objects)
      .mapToInt(?)
      .toArray();
```

Comment: It is possible, but not from a stream of the _values_. You essentially need a stream of _keys_, which in this case are just the indices of the array. So `IntStream.range(0, objects.length)` gives you the indices, and can be collected with `#toMap`: `.collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> objects[i]));`, providing a `Map<Integer, Obj>`

Answer (score 2):

Stream, an **internal iterator**, it's meant to process elements from the source lazily until the source is exhausted. That's the whole point of streams, you're **not** controlling the process of iteration (that's what *internal iterator* means), all you need to care about the business logic.

Sure, you can iterate over the array's indices using [`IntStream.range()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range(int,int)) as *@Rogue* has mentioned in the comments, but it's a contrived way of streaming over the array. It brings unnecessary complexity. If you have an array - [`Arrays.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(T%5B%5D)) that's what you need.

Every time you want to use an array's indices while iterating through it using a Stream, pause for a second, most likely traditional index-based `for`-loop would be more suitable for what you're doing.